# Calibrate accelerometer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, accelerometer

So I'm moving a `SKSpriteNode` around the screen via device tilt using the accelerometer. How would I go about calibrating the accelerometer to apply forces based on changes in device orientation from where it started on the app starting.

For example: If I'm holding my device straight up and down, on start up the `SKSpriteNode` will just drop to the bottom of the screen. How can I essentially set that starting device orientation to 0?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not the accelerometer but the Core Motion CMDeviceMotion. You can then use the `attitude` to do what you describe. Use the `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical` frame of reference, store the initial attitude, and call `multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:` for all subsequent attitudes to learn what the change is from the initial attitude.